# Draw gradient along a path in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, core-image

I've found quite a few sample that archived kind of a similar result, but what I want is to draw a multi-line gradient along an arbitrary path. (I need it to visualize users speed during a run on a MapView)

So the gradient will have quite a few colors and colorLocations.
What I've see so far is one gradient and this one is masked to a path. But that's not what I need.

So the result I want it something like the Nike Runners Club App. They draw a beautiful gradient.

So it should look something like this: [image]

Comment: Include an image of what you *want* as an end result... tough to figure out from just a description.

Comment: Hmmm... your image looks like a simple masked gradient. That is, the line doesn't go from green to red to blue to yellow... it goes green to red to green, and the line is just masked over it. Is that sufficient for your task? Or do you really need "end-to-end" colors?

Comment: Yes, the design I got just uses a simple gradient... but the end-result should allow arbitrary paths with arbitrary speed-color-coding

Comment: I'm assuming you're constructing the full path from point-to-point segments? If so, you will probably need to apply gradients to each section as an individual path, as opposed to all the segments joined into one path.

Comment: Yes. but that will leave ugly edges... so the parts where one line ends and the new one starts... especially when being zoomed out (but ok... I could simplify my path when beeing zommed out... this could make it look a bit better, but not as sexy as nike)

Comment: *"Not as sexy as nike"* ... do you have an image-cap of a path in the nike app that looks how you're going for?

Comment: They also don't do it perfekt. If you run the same road back and forth, they will have artifacts... but they look something like that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ed4zjfv1arvi5mm/nike-sample.png?dl=0

Comment: You can cut your line into segmentsm attach color to each segments and then interpolate color betwen neighbouring colors depending on distance. More segments you will have smoother gradient you will achieve.